# Business guy in love with coding - May I post answers to my textbook?

Tags: discussion

I am currently learning to program with a book called Learn to Program. I would like to contribute posting the code I have built as solutions to the problems on the book. It would be my way of retributing to the community, to help other students. What are your views on this? Are such posts accepted on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Posting answers to student exercises does not help them.  At all.  Use a blog.

Comment: Either a blog or a GitHub account would be better. I've posted exercise solutions on both and gotten good feedback from people who have found it useful.  It doesn't have to be on Stack Overflow for people to find it via searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can ask a quality question that meets all of the site's standards for an acceptable question, and also provide an answer that meets all of the site's standards for an appropriate answer, then you're welcome to post a question and answer it.  Just keep in mind that the fact that you are answering your own question in no way relaxes the quality standards for either the question or the answer; both will be evaluated independently of each other, and as if they weren't asked by the same person.

Comment: @Deduplicator I fail to see how it would be a problem for self answered questions to be most of a user's contributions, so long as they are actually asking quality questions and providing quality answers.  Of course, providing quality self answered questions is very hard, deceptively so, and as a result most people self-answering aren't providing quality contributions.